# Java:  Returning Infinity

Tags: java, multithreading, math, parallel-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ConcurrentHashMap: Can we trust on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599949/concurrenthashmap-can-we-trust-on-it)

The following expression is returning infinity for me.

```
 Double sum =0.0; 
 sum = sum + Math.exp(getScore(contextFeatureVector,entry.getValue())+constant);
```

Here `getScore` calculates inner product of two vectors.

```
        Constant = 0.00001
```

Vectors value ranges from [-0.01,0.01],  `entry.getValue()`  is read/write by a number of threads. `entry.getValue()` is value of an hashmap as:

```
 Map<Integer,ArrayList<Double>> anEntry = new ConcurrentHashmap();
```

Comment: `Math.exp`... hmm... how large is the parameter that's getting passed to it?

Comment: vector size around 150 in dimension.And score value can sometime reach upto some thousands.

Comment: I mean like, what is `getScore()` returning? I suspect it's returning something big. So `Math.exp()` is overflowing.

Comment: That seems to be the problem then. Overflow. So you'll need to redesign what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: it returns **double** value. It may reach upto some thousands. Not more than that. IT is because, it is sum of product of doubles that range between **[0.01,-0.01]**

Comment: Anything larger than about `709` will cause overflow on `Math.exp()`.

Comment: it will get larger than that. Any other way to handle it?

Comment: Well, a `double` can't handle anything larger than about `10^308`. If you really need to handle numbers that large, you will need a different approach. Perhaps try log-scale arithmetic?

Comment: the value does not get higher than that.Do you thing it is due to parallel computing and synchronization problem?I am  using Concurrent hashmap for concurrency.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14240/discussion-between-thetna-and-mysticial)