# ConcurrentHashMap: Can we trust on it?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

From the document of ConcurrentHashMap:

> A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and adjustable expected concurrency for updates.

Can we fully believe that `ConcurrentHashMap` does thread safe operation?

I am using ConcurrentHashMap for mapping key with their values.My key-value pair is:

```
Map<Integer,ArrayList<Double>> map1 = new ConcurrentHashMap();
```

The size of key ranges from [0,1000000]. I have 20 threads which can access/modify value corresponding to a key at a time. This not so frequent but  that condition is possible. I am
getting an infinity from following method:

```
Double sum =0.0; 
sum = sum + Math.exp(getScore(contextFeatureVector,entry.getValue())+constant);
```

`contextFeatureVector` and  `entry.getValue()`are arraylist associated with a key.

[EDIT]

```
 constant =0.0001

private double getScore(List<Double> featureVector,List<Double>weightVector) throws NullPointerException    
{
    double score =0.0;
    int length = featureVector.size();
    for (int i =0 ; i< length ; i++){
    score = score + (featureVector.get(i)*weightVector.get(i)); 
    }

    return score;
}
```

Both `featureVector<> and weightVector looks like`

```
[-0.005554038592516575, 0.0048966974158881175, -0.05315976588195846, -0.030837804373964654, 0.014483064988148562, -0.018962129117649, -0.015221386014208877, 0.015825702365331477, -0.11363620479662287, 0.00802609847263844, -0.062106636476812194, 0.008108854471293185, -0.03193255218671684, 0.04949650992670292, -0.0545583154094599, -0.04873314092706468, 0.013534731656877033, 0.08433117163682455, 0.050310355477044114, -0.002420513353516017, -0.02708299928442614, -0.023489187394176294, -0.1277699782685597, -0.10071004855129333, 0.08649040730064464, -0.04940329664431305, -0.027481729446035053, -0.0571846057609884, -0.036738550618481455, -0.035608113682344365]
```

thus the value returned from getScore does not go exceptionally too large. it will be in 
some thousands.

Comment: Yes, we can trust `ConcurrentHashMap`.  That's kind of the point.  There's sure to be some other reason why you're getting the infinity; but without knowing what `getScore` does, or what `constant` is, it's hard to tell.

Comment: So what would be the largest number that you'd expect to be returned from `getScore`?

Comment: So, if you go `exp( a few thousand )`, you'll exceed the limits of a `double`.  That's why you're getting infinity.

Comment: what can we use for holding larger than this?

Answer (score 3):

It is thread safe, but can use it an manner which is not thread safe.

I suspect you haven't investigated the problem enough to determine that there is a bug in a JDK library which has been used for more than a decade.

Comment: Not the ConcurrentHashMap.  That's not a decade old, but the rest of your point is well taken.  The problem is far more likely to be bad code from the user, not the JDK.

Comment: It predates Java 5.0 http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/intro.html

Answer (score 3):

The data structure you use makes me believe there must some bug in your code. Most likely you are fetching the list from map and updating it:

```
map1.get(42).add(5);
```

Note that `add(5)` is **not** thread-safe as it operates on ordinary `ArrayList`. You either need thread safe `ArrayList` or [`replace(K key, V oldValue, V newValue)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#replace%28K,%20V,%20V%29) method.

If you read carefully through the guarantees `ConcurrentHashMap` is giving, you can use it effectively.

Comment: `replace()` sucks hard to ArrayList-alike values b/c it has to compared all the elements in the collection - if they (the ArrayList) are equal by reference it's ok, otherwise truly uncool. Other than that `replace()` is the correct approach but not while using collections.

Answer (score 2):

If you call `Math.exp(...)` on an input that is too large you will get an Infinity.  That is the probably cause of your problems ... not some imagined problem with the thread safety.

I suggest that you add some trace code to see what

```
 getScore(contextFeatureVector, entry.getValue())
```

is returning when `sum` becomes an Infinity.  Beyond that, I don't think we'll be able to help without seeing more of your code.

Answer (score 1):

The largest number that can be stored in a Java `double` is approximately `exp(709)`.  So if you pass anything larger than 709 into `exp()`, you should expect to get an arithmetic overflow.